# extrapolation shows unexpected pattern nonlinear model R

Tags: r, regression, curve-fitting, prediction

I have a data of number of unique genetic variants found upon stepwise addition of genetic samples. I want to build a model to see approximately how many samples are required to find the complete number of genetic variants. I tried the curve fitting with 2 to 5 degree polynomial equations (cumulative count of new variants `KWB` as my response variable and the count of sample `Sample` as my explanatory variable ). Then using the best fit model I tried to  extrapolate the response variable i.e. cumulative count of new variants (`KWB`) .. The plot shows it exponentially increasing but it is supposed to be saturated at some point. Here is my code.

```
t <- subset(su, !is.na(KWP))
t$pred1 <- predict(lm(KWP ~ poly(Sample, 2, raw = TRUE), data=t))
p1 <- ggplot(t, aes(x = Sample, y=KWP)) + geom_line() + geom_point()
print(p1)
p1 + geom_line(aes(y = pred1), color="red")
pred <- data.frame(Sample=1:300)
pred$KWP <- predict(lm(KWP ~ poly(Sample, 2, raw = TRUE), data=t),newdata=pred)
p1 + geom_line(color="red", data=pred)
```

[Here is the data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BPn2GGpo0CSzV1NVpvNUN0a1E) 
[image]

Comment: polynomials are awful for extrapolation - do not use them. Perhaps try a hyperbolic fit.

Comment: Actually,  it does not show exponential increase. It shows increase like a degree 2 polynomial.

Comment: If KWB is saturated at some point, a polynomial is not a good choice.  Try with a different model, like `y = a(1 – exp(-b*x))` or `y = a*x/(b +x) `

Comment: Can you please help me how to do this in R